# Why does jgejala = drkonsultasi.item(0) evaluate to invalid operation?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, oledb

I have this code:

```
comkonsultasi = New OleDbCommand("select count(idkonsultasi) from dkonsultasi where idgejala='" & idgejala & "'", conn)
    drkonsultasi = comkonsultasi.ExecuteReader
    jgejala = drkonsultasi.Item(0)
```

When it runs, I get this exception message on the last line:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled. No data exists for the row/column.

Can anyone can help to resolve this problem?

Comment: Call `Read()` on the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `Read()` from the DataReader. It's also **very bad** to use string concatenation to put data into an SQL query like that. You must use query parameters instead:

```
Dim sql As String = "select count(idkonsultasi) from dkonsultasi where idgejala= ?"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
      comkonsultasi As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    'Use the actual type and length from the database for this line
    comkonsultasi.Parameters.Add("idgejala", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50).Value = idgejala 
    conn.Open()
    Using drkonsultasi As OleDbDataReader = comkonsultasi.ExecuteReader()
        If drkonsultasi.Read() Then
            jgejala = drkonsultasi.Item(0)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```